# How to import library into swift code used in CLI?

Tags: swift, command-line-interface, alamofire

#### What I want to do

I want to try to get son file through API by swift library on CLI.
I am using the library, Alamofire, but I can't understand how to import swift library.

Maybe some tasks are needed before import (building? linking?) but I can't find how to document...
Could you teach me how to do it?

#### Problem

```
$ swift getAPI.swift
getAPI.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'Alamofire'
import Alamofire
       ^
```

#### Sourcecode

```
import Alamofire

func getArticles(){
  Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://qiita.com/api/v2/items")
    .responseJSON { response in
      print(response.result.value )
    }
}

getArticles()
```

Comment: It's overkill to use a huge third party library for such a simple GET request. Use `URLSession`. But consider that any asynchronous task requires a runloop.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I did not know `URLSession`. I will use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should help with running one-off scripts and when using the Swift REPL. However, for building simple tools for the command line, I would recommend using the [Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/) since it takes care of the linking and dependency management for you.

---

To link your script code to the Alamofire library, the swift compiler has to know where to the library is located. By default it searches /Library/Frameworks, but we can supply options to tell it where else to look. Checking `swift --help`, we see the following options (among many others).

```
USAGE: swift [options] <inputs>

OPTIONS:
  -F <value>    Add directory to framework search path
  -I <value>    Add directory to the import search path
  -L <value>    Add directory to library link search path
```

The directory you supply must to contain the compiled binaries of the libraries you want to import.

- To import `.swiftmodule` binaries, use `-I`
- To import `.framework` binaries, use `-F`
- For linking to libraries like libsqlite3.0.dylib, use `-L`

I think Carthage and CocoaPods will build frameworks, whereas the Swift Package Manager will build `.swiftmodules`. All three should put the binaries in very predictable locations. Different kinds of binaries may all be in the same  and that's okay.

**Putting it all together,** if you build with SPM, your invocation might look like this:

```
$ swift -I .build/debug/
```

But if you manage dependencies with Carthage, it might look something like this:

```
$ swift -F ./Carthage/Build/iOS
```

**For further reading,** I found these resources useful:

- [krakendev.io/blog/scripting-in-swift](https://krakendev.io/blog/scripting-in-swift)
- [realm.io/news/swift-scripting/](https://realm.io/news/swift-scripting/)

**Update:** The Swift package manager can now take care of this for you as well! If you're writing a script as a package and include a bunch of dependencies, like Alamofire, you can now test them out in the REPL. Just `cd` into your package directory and launch it using `swift run --repl`. See [the swift.org blog](https://swift.org/blog/swiftpm-repl-support/) for more details.